# bash: Search similar word from text file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a sample text file `abc.txt` which contains some values:

```
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1
Hairy Potter - C:Harry:1:1:1
```

The `:` is the separator between the values. Currently, I am trying to `grep` similar values and compare to the first column and print out the lines.

```
grep -i "harry" BookDB.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $0}'
```

It produces:

```
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1
Hairy Potter - C:Harry:1:1:1
```

However, the results I am trying to achieve is:

```
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1
```

any help?

Answer (score 2):

All that `awk -F ':' '{print $0}'` does is print every line, it does nothing in your example.

If you want to do this with `awk` it would be:

```
$ awk -F: '$1~/Harry/' file
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1

# Case insensitive 
$ awk -F: 'tolower($1)~/harry/' file
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1
```

This only prints the line if the first field `$1` matches `/Harry/`, the case insensitive version converts the first field to all lowercase characters and checks against `/harry/`.

You could just anchor `harry` to the start of the line with `^` if you know this is always the case?

```
$ grep -i "^harry" file
Harry Potter - A:JK:1:1:1
Harry Potter - B:JK:1:1:1
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely the way to go for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

so you want it to only grep on the first part of the line, before the first occurence of ":" separator?

let's say you are sure there is no "%" in your file: 
1) you replace the FIRST (and only first) occurence of ":" by the unused character (% or another) and show lines where you can your string before that %

```
sed -e 's/:/%/' < BookDB.txt | grep -i '^[^%]*harry[^%]*%'
```

or if all lines contain " - ": simplify it as such:

```
sed -e 's/:/%/' < BookDB.txt | grep -i '^[^%]*harry'
```

and add to this

```
| sed -e 's/%/:/' # to restore the original line
```

In the above, you can replace ":" with, for example, " - " (a multi-character separator), and it will still work.

If you really need just to find something before the first occurence of a single character, you can simplify further as such (but it's less flexible):

```
grep -i '^[^:]*harry[^:]*:'
```

or

```
grep -i '^[^:]*harry'
```

(2nd should probably only be used if all the lines are in a similar format as the ones you need to match things in)

Comment: and to verify you don't have any of the "unused char" : `grep '%' BookDB.txt || echo "ok, didn't find it."`

Comment: on bash: ctrl+v followed by, for example, ctrl+e, will insert a "^E" special chars that is unlikely to be fuodn at all in BookDB.txt. Replace then all the "%" above with "ctrl+v ctrl+e". To do it portably (ie, easy to copy/paste), define : `export unusedchar="$(printf '\005')"` . And then change the lines above to : `sed -e 's/ - /'${unusedchar}'/' < BookDB.txt | grep '^[^'${unusedchar}']*harry'`

Comment: um... i am trying to grep on the part before the first ":" not "-".

Comment: then easy: change " - " above with ":" : it will work too (replacing only the first occurence of it with the unused char, etc)

Comment: There are many ways this can be done, I don't recommend doing it like this however!

Comment: Please capitalize conventionally.

Comment: @thb : where? in the script? or in my sentences?

Answer (score -2):

If you just looking for `Harry` in the first argument the command below will do the trick

`grep -i "harry " BookDB.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $0}'`

However if you need a full book name you have to write a bash script which will extract the book name and compares it to your input.

Comment: How is this different from what the OP already has, piping anything through `awk -F ':' '{print $0}'` does nothing as it just prints the lines.